# Warum wurde das Futur II auch »Exaktfutur« genannt?

Tags: etymology, terminology, future

Durch Christian Morgensterns Gedicht *Unter Zeiten* ¹ bin ich darauf aufmerksam geworden, dass das Futur II zuweilen auch *Exaktfutur* oder auch *Futurum exaktum* genannt wurde.

Ich kann mir keinen besseren Reim auf die Herkunft dieser Bezeichnung machen, als dass das Futur II nur in einer sehr exakten Sprache benötigt wird. Dies ist aber nur eine vage Vermutung und überzeugt mich nicht wirklich.

Der [zugehörige Duden-Eintrag](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Futurum_exaktum) legt nahe, dass die Kombination direkt aus dem Lateinischen stammt. Dort ist *exactum* das Partizip Passiv zu *exigere,* das wiederum *einfordern, fordern* oder *treiben* bedeutet – was auch kein Licht in die Sache bringt.

Meine Frage lautet daher: Was ist der Grund für diese Bezeichnung?

---

¹

> Das Perfekt und das Imperfekt
>      tranken Sekt.
> Sie stießen aufs Futurum an
> (was man wohl gelten lassen kann).
>
> Plusquamper und Exaktfutur
>     blintzen nur.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lateinisch *exigere* kann noch mehr Bedeutungen haben; der [Eintrag bei Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=exigo) gibt unter II. B. 2 an:

> Of time, life, etc., *to lead, spend, pass, complete, finish*

Und das ist ja gerade, was das Futur II ausdrückt: Eine Handlung, die zu dem beschriebenen Zeitpunkt in der Zukunft bereits beendet bzw. abgeschlossen ist.

Comment: Sieht so aus, als hätte ich einen Ticken zu früh aufgegeben, eine Spur zu verfolgen.